# Возращение кода ошибки при переполнении

Tags: c, массивы

Как в функции read_array вернуть код ошибки при переполнении?
Если массив уже заполнен,а концевой признак еще не наступил, ввод элементов в массиве прекращается.
Такое переполнение не считается ошибкой:программа должна обработатЬ полученый массив из 10 элементов,
но функция main в такой ситуации должна вернуть специальный код ошибки,равный 100.

```
int read_array(int *arr, int n)
{
    printf("Enter elements in array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != 1)
        {
            printf("Error: Mistake in input!\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }
    return 100;
}
```

Спасибо заранее

Comment: Возвращайте всегда количество реально прочитанных элементов (а в случае ошибки ввода отрицательное число), пусть вызывающий код сам решает, как ему поступить если оно меньше заказанного.

Comment: Есть куча приёмов для обработки ошибок. Старый способ сделать свой глобальный `int errno=0;`

Comment: Moжете привести пример?

Comment: @Spizzy, если в комментарии спрашиваете конкретного участника, то используйте запись `@nick`